# Is there a standard video logo size? When could a 1500px png logo 300 ppi size be possibly needed?

Tags: animation, video, multiple-sizes

Is there a standard video logo size? When could a 1500px png logo 300 ppi size be possibly needed?

[image: logo size for sample purposes only]

Comment: @joojaa already said it pretty much everything, but man, this seems suuuper vague. You need it when you need it. There aren't any standard sizes unless it's a very specific use case. The size can depend on how it's used too. **My first question would be, do you have this in a vector format?** In which case the size wouldn't matter.

Comment: @Joonas yeah they probably want to animate the logo anyway so they need to break ot up anyway.

Comment: PPI/DPI have nothing to do with video. All that matters is the image size in pixels. It depends on how big you want the image to be, or what you need to do with it. Also note that video editing is generally off-topic here.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that a 1500px image is still a 1500px image regardless of the ppi/dpi setting.  A 1500px image at 72 ppi is exactly the same as a 1500px image at 300 ppi.  If you don't understand why, check out [The Myth of DPI](http://www.rideau-info.com/photos/mythdpi.html) - an old but still very useful article.

Answer (score 1):

First lets talk about the PPI/DPI thing. Its entirely irrelevant for the context of video production. It literally never comes to play.

Second a full hd aka 1080p image is 1920 x 1080 pixels in size so ideally youd have a version of the logo thats designed exactly for those pixel dimensions, with whitespace and all. But 4k consumer (4k UHD) devices are 3840 × 2160 pixels, and cinema (DCI 4k) devices are 4096 × 2160. Not to talk about 8k stuff.

So for any modern video producer a 1500 pixel logo seems a bit low resolution indeed. But why they wouldnt use the vector files beats me?

So to directly answer the question:

> When could a 1500px png logo 300 ppi size be possibly needed?

Every time they need a full screen logo. So pretty much at the start of each video.

Answer (score 1):

You are not thinking in the correct context.

A video has a specific pixel resolution if you want to specifically target an optimum display.

For example FullHD has specific dimensions of 1920x1080px. So, define your logo on how it should be using a canvas of that specific size. It does not matter the pixel size. That pixel size is how you want it to be.

> Is there a standard video logo size

Thank god no. Why would anyone want a standardized look on a logo on a video? Make the logo any size you need or want.

But something to take into account is that some video edition programs can use either a vector logo file or a raster one.

If you want to have a logo on a higher resolution screen, make it bigger than the one needed for HD, so you do not see a pixelation or use a vector version and define whatever size during editing.